# how to get default port number on which web application is running (or deployed) using javascript

Tags: javascript, port

I have a web application which is deployed at some port say 8085, and hostname is sample.something.com. Using window.location.host or window.location.port, the port is coming as blank.
How can i retrieve the port number using javascript , can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the port you are testing this? 80?

Answer (score 3):

If `window.location.port` is empty that means the application is running on port 80 for http and 443 for https.

As mentioned in a comment, you can use `window.location.protocol` to check what protocol is used (http or https).

Implementation:

```
function getPort(){
  if(location.port != ''){
      return location.port;
  }
  else if(location.protocol== 'http'){
     return 80;    
  }
  else if(location.protocol== 'https'){
     return 443;    
  }    
}
```

Comment: And for that you can use `location.protocol`

Comment: i second that, not always 80 port is assigned to default. Network adminstrators maintain different ports to disable attacks or secure them.

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet how browser going to recognize that?

Comment: the url is an alias name for an ip of a hosted content, say your content is in xx.xx.xx.xx ip an alias name is given for the same like samplewebsite.com, you register the name and map it to an IP, the webserver running on that IP handles the calls, the name and ip correlation are managed by the name servers. agree ?

Comment: My question is if I type http://www.myserver.com/ and my server is listening on port 8888. is page will load without any intermediate listener running on port 80.

Comment: Your name server will return matching ip for myserver.com as your ip:8888 , just a thought have you managed any web hosting ? Possibly more than me a person who actually maintains the web server farm can give you a better answer, try with one of your network guys

Comment: If that doesn't help let's post a question in the same and set a bounty and verify :)

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet any thing verified?