# Can network admin change the default port for http

Tags: http, networking, port, admin

I gave an answer to following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601001/how-to-get-default-port-number-on-which-web-application-is-running-or-deployed/12601071#comment16983919_12601071). but in the comment a user suggested that network admin can change the default port of http from 80 to something else.
As for as I know if I open a page eg. http://www.example.com without port that means it is running on port 80.

I just want to clarify that is it possible for network admin to change default port?

Comment: And this has to do with JavaScript why?

Comment: If no port is specified in the url the useragent will default to 80, if one is specified with :XXX then it will use that port

Comment: @epascarello no. I removed JavaScript tag.

Comment: @AlexK. this what I know. just wanted to confirm it. see the comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601001/how-to-get-default-port-number-on-which-web-application-is-running-or-deployed/12601071#comment16983919_12601071

Comment: The comment is misleading, 80 is *always* the default for http on the *client* side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a browser, http://www.example.com will always try and connect to the server's TCP port 80, like it's port 443 for HTTPS connections. These port numbers (defined [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt)) are hard coded in any browser.

Yet a web server can be configured to listen to any other port, which rarely makes sense though. If it does, the browser will be unable to connect (unless the port no. is explicitly given as in http://myserver.com:81).

Comment: ...provided that no proxy is configured in the browser.