# How to hide port used from website / domain URL?

Tags: node.js, apache, ssh, port, hosting

Right now my next JS app is running on port 30000. I can access this on the domain just fine with the port showing on the end:

```
www.examplesite.com:30000
```

How can i just access it like this, without the port but still serves the content in port 30000?

```
www.examplesite.com
```

Unfortunately i cannot use port 80, the only available port from the hosting service is only 30000-50000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can network admin change the default port for http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601397/can-network-admin-change-the-default-port-for-http)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25974027/13317

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, by default url `www.examplesite.com` is just an alias of `www.examplesite.com:80`.
Contact your domain provider and sort out how could you get access to one of default ports: 80(http) / 443(https).